# Java Abstract Methods

Tags: java, abstract-class

I am slightly confused with the keyword `abstract` here. My compiler is telling me that I am not allowed to have a body for a method that's abstract. However my assignment says:

> The abstract method orderDescription() returns a String giving details about a particular order.

```
abstract String orderDescription()
{
    return null;
}
```

However my code returns an error, as I mentioned above.  So my question is what should I do for this problem?

Up to now I've just removed the keyword abstract and it works fine.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
abstract String orderDescription()
{
    return null;
}
```

should be

```
abstract String orderDescription();
```

As error says, your abstract method declaration shouldn't contain any body.

Above syntax mandates the implementation (which ever class extends the abstract class and provides implementation) to return a String.

You can't instantiate abstract class, so some class need to extend abstract class and provide implementation for this abstract method.

Example:

```
class MyabsClass 
{
  abstract String orderDescription();
}

class MyImplementation extends MyabsClass
{
   public String orderDescription()
    {
    return "This is description";
    }
}



 class MyClient
   {
     public static void main(String[] args)
      {
         MyImplementation imple = new MyImplementation();
         imple.orderDescription();
      }
   }
```

Comment: I understand that, as abstract methods cannot have bodies to them. But I am supposed to return a String so how would return something if I can't have a body?

Comment: @user1327636: Updated answer with theory. Shortly will provide an example.

Comment: @user1327636, That responsibility is delegated to the subclass that inherits this abstract method, but the return type constraint is enforced through the language by the parent class.

Comment: @Nambari If a class includes abstract methods, then the class itself must be declared abstract. MyabsClass must be defined as abstract.

Answer (score 13):

When you **define** an abstract method, you are telling the compiler that any subclasses must provide an implementation (or also declare themselves abstract).

You **implement** the abstract method in a subclass.

Remember, you cannot create instances of abstract classes themselves.  The entire point of an abstract method is to tell the compiler that you want subclasses to provide the functionality.

Comment: This should be the answer. An abstract class can have code, it, however, cannot be instantiated. The abstract class must be subclassed.

Answer (score 6):

Essentially, an abstract function shouldn't contain any details, it is a placeholder function for inherited functions. As Nambari stated, you should only include the definition.

This is used for when you want a family of classes to all contain a common function, which you wish each child class to define.

Answer (score 4):

Abstract methods generally shouldn't contain any "real" code, abstract methods are to be overidden by non-abstract classes containing the method.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract method should not have any method body. It allows only method declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Also, adding to Nambari's example, what you can do is

```
class MyabsClass 
{
  abstract String orderDescription();
}

 class MyClient
   {
     public static void main(String[] args)
      {
         MyabsClass mac = new MyabsClass(){
              public String orderDescription()
              {
                     return "This is description";
              }
         };
         mac.orderDescription();
      }
   }
```

That is, through anonymous class.